# Use '@angular/material:ng-add' generator from within an nx-plugin-generator

Tags: angular, angular-material, nrwl-nx

I would like to use the '@angular/material:ng-add' generator from within [my custom nx-plugin-generator](https://github.com/qubitme/abc/blob/master/packages/xangular/src/generators/application/application.ts).

First I run the application generator, which installs the required dependencies [@angular/material, @angular/cdk].

```
export default async function (tree: Tree, options: ApplicationGeneratorOptions) {
  const { appName, } = normalizeOptions(tree, options);

  const angularInitOptions: AngularInitOptions = {...};
  await angularInitGenerator(tree, angularInitOptions);

  const angularAppOptions: AngularApplicationOptions = {...};
  await applicationGenerator(tree, angularAppOptions);

  const addDepsToTargetWorkspace = addDependenciesToPackageJson(tree, {
    '@angular/material': VERSIONS.ANGULAR_MATERIAL,
    '@angular/cdk': VERSIONS.ANGULAR_CDK,
  }, {});

  await formatFiles(tree);
  return addDepsToTargetWorkspace;
```

After that I run the material generator. It is supposed to update several files [styles.scss, index.html, app.module.ts, etc.].

```
  export default async function (tree: Tree, options: MaterialGeneratorSchema) {
  const { appName } = normalizeOptions(tree, options);

  const ngAddOptions: NgAddOptions = { project: appName, animations: 'enabled', theme: 'indigo-pink', typography: true };

  const ngAddMaterialGenerator = wrapAngularDevkitSchematic('@angular/material', 'ng-add');

  await ngAddMaterialGenerator(tree, ngAddOptions);

  return () => {
    logger.info(`Nx Qmaterial Generator: ${appName} has been generated.`);
  }
}
```

When I execute the material-generator, it generates NOTHING at all, even though both required dependencies are present in the node_modules [@angular/material, @angular/cdk].

The logger in the callback method informs me that it has been generated, but the files don't change at all.

[--- link to the repo ---](https://github.com/qubitme/abc)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the ngAddMaterialGenerator function is not properly executing due to an error, but the logger is not catching it. You can try wrapping the await ngAddMaterialGenerator(tree, ngAddOptions) line in a try-catch block to see if any errors are being thrown:

```
try {
  await ngAddMaterialGenerator(tree, ngAddOptions);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

You can also try adding some additional logging statements inside the ngAddMaterialGenerator function to see if it's being called and if any errors are being thrown.

Comment: Hi @Jamshed, I updated my question and provided a link to the repo. Can you re-check, please?